# Does np.where not work with vague datetime parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, python-datetime

I have a df where I am trying to populate a new column by having np.where look for yesterday's date, then assign the value of "total_count" to new_col if the "sales_datetime" equals yesterday. If it doesn't, I just want it to show 0.

I put in a couple of dt formulas that are working properly, my np.where works BUT it is showing new_col as all zeros, even when "sales_datetime" is equal to yesterday.

Changing my np.where to be a specific date yields the result I'm looking for, but I'd like this to be able to iterate daily without having to manually change the date that should be checked against.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. Setting up yesterday value:

   ```
    today = dt.today().date()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    print(today)
    print(yesterday)

    2022-06-01

    2022-05-31
   ```
2. np.where statement

   ```
   df['new_col'] = np.where(df['sale_datetime'] == yesterday, df['total_count'], 0)
   ```
3. Current result

   ```
    sale_datetime   item1   item2   total_count new_col
    2022-05-27        3       9          12        0
    2022-05-31        0       7           7        0
    2022-05-05        6       8          14        0
    2022-05-31        5       5          10        0
    2022-05-25        0      16          16        0
   ```
4. Desired/expected result

   ```
    sale_datetime   item1   item2   total_count new_col
    2022-05-27        3       9          12        0
    2022-05-31        0       7           7        7
    2022-05-05        6       8          14        0
    2022-05-31        5       5          10       10
    2022-05-25        0      16          16        0
   ```

Comment: The `where` is only as good as the condition argument, here `df['sale_datetime'] == yesterday`

Comment: Understood, I may be getting lost/confused with that column then. df.info() shows it as datetime64 so I was under the impression I could use my "yesterday" function to parse through that column of datetimes with the "yesterday" datetime.date to find matches. But that seems to be where the disconnect is and giving me all zeros as output.

Comment: Try `== pd.Timestamp(yesterday)` in place of `== yesterday`

Comment: That still is resulting in only zero values in new_col. I have found a non-Pandas workaround to my specific problem, happy to keep plugging away at this one though to help anyone who may encounter similar issue.

Comment: How is `df` created? It will be difficult to determine the issue without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).